# Rails controller params are null, even though I can see them in debug output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Disclaimer: super new to rails. I'm using Rails 3.2

Anyways, I'm trying to create a form for Merchants to sign in. I have a MerchantSessionsController that tries to create a new session based on signin form input:

This is what I have in my 
app/views/merchant_sessions/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(:merchant_session, :url => merchant_sessions_path) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :userName %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :userName %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign in" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The file app\controllers\merchant_sessions_controller.rb contains:

```
def create
    merchant = Merchant.find_by_userName(params[:userName])

    if merchant && merchant.authenticate(params[:password])
        merchant_session[:merchant_id] = merchant.id
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Merchanthas been logged in"
    else
        flash.now[:error] = "Invalid username or password."
        @title  = "Merchant Signin"
        render "new"
    end
end
```

Unfortunately, the params[:userName] and params[:password] keep getting passed as nil, even though on the debug output on the merchants signin page, I see that the userName and password are definitely being passed in.

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
utf8: ✓
authenticity_token: 8WsOviJyY1kktPq9dDO+OFePdSKf2uGLY3Pnc4bU2tc=
merchant_session: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  userName: asd
  password: ddsad
commit: Sign in
action: create
controller: merchant_sessions
```

I've also attempted to access the params[:action] parameter, which worked fine. Why is it that the userName and password parameters are nil? I had changed the name of the MerchantSessionsController (formerly just SessionsController), but I don't think that should be the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking in the wrong place for the username and password, note the specific structure of your YAML dump:

```
merchant_session: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  userName: asd
  password: ddsad
```

and your form:

```
<%= form_for(:merchant_session, :url => merchant_sessions_path) do |f| %>
```

You want to look at `params[:merchant_session][:userName]` and `params[:merchant_session][:password]` instead of `params[:userName]` and `params[:password]`:

```
def create
    mparams  = params[:merchant_session]
    merchant = Merchant.find_by_userName(mparams[:userName])

    if merchant && merchant.authenticate(mparams[:password])
        #...
```

Comment: I figured this out about one minute before you posted the answer. Ahh, isn't amazing how you can know so much about one framework but still make complete noob mistakes in another?

Comment: @yaj786: And it is amazing how hard it is too see something that's staring you right in the face :) Those are some of the hardest bugs to see.